# How to access a LinkedList inside of main from my Jframe button call

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jframe

:::::: UPDATE :::::

I tried updating my `JFrame` to take a LinkedList as an argument, it looks like...

```
 public userLogin(LinkedList<dataUser> ll) {
    initComponents();
 }
```

My main is now calling it by ...

```
userLogin frame = new userLogin(userLL);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Still not able to use the LinkedList userLL inside of my `JFrame`

:::::: END UPDATE ::::::

It's my first time using netbeans and the GUI builder. I have a class `TaskManager` that I'm using as my main class. This class creates a few `LinkedList`s and calls my first `JFrame` GUI like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<dataUser> userLL = new LinkedList<dataUser>(); //creates a LL for userData
    LinkedList<task> taskLL = new LinkedList<task>(); //creates a LL for taskData
    LinkedList<task> progressLL = new LinkedList<task>(); //creates a LL for in progress tasks
    LinkedList<task> completeLL = new LinkedList<task>(); //creates a LL for completed tasks

    userLogin frame = new userLogin();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

However, inside my `userLogin` I can't access the `userLL` that I created.
Here is the code inside my submit button:

```
private void submitBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    String user = jTextField1.getText();
    String userPW = jTextField2.getText();

    try {
        //below userLL is not accessible because it can't be found.
        dataUser.userDataSearch(userLL, userPW);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "was not found", "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        return;
    }
}
```

As the comment in the code states, I can't run the function because I do not have access to `userLL` (the `LinkedList` I created in my main program that launches this `JFrame`).

Do I have to pass in the `LinkedList` into my `JFrame` as an argument for it to be able to use it?  I assumed declaring it in main would make allow access, but it appears to be local to main now.

Comment: Your thoughts seem to be pretty much correct.

Comment: I added the LinkedList argument into my main and my 'JFrame' still doesn't have access.  Updating the main post to show.

Comment: can you show us your `initComponents();` body ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass the `userLL` as parameter to your `userLogin` class like this :

```
public class userLogin {

    LinkedList<dataUser> userLL

    public userLogin(List userLL){
        this.userLL = userLL;
    }

    //.......
}
```

And in your main class instantiate it like this : `userLogin frame = new userLogin(userLL);`

Comment: This works great, thank you.  However, will it maintain any data that main gave the LinkedList with this method?

Answer (score 2):

You created a class userlogin that extends JFrame (this magic was done by Netbeans). The main class is just a entry point for your program, and the scope of main is unknowned to the userlogin class.

You have to options (you have others with static declarations, but we must not consider that ones):

1. Pass the data you will need to handling by the class, using the constructor like @Maraboc post
2. Create a setter method in the UserLogin class to set the list or other data, but you will need to be sure that data will be setted when you will need it.

There are other options to make available external data to a class in the context of a program. Using some Singleton pattern (ex: GlobalDataStorageSingleton) what could be a bad design according with the SOLID paradigms.

You can view SOLID vs STUPID principles in OOP.

Best
Pedro

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to solve this.

- You already mentioned the first one: pass the `LinkedList` (either in the constructor or later, via some setter method).
- The second option would be declaring the `LinkedList` an object variable of your main class and accessing it using a getter. If you do not have a reference to the main class object, a static variable should do the trick (if there's one instance of the `LinkedList` only.

I would definitely recommend option 1, as it's the *standard way to go* and access to the list is limited way better.

Answer (score 1):

You wont have access to the Lists created within the main() class. You would have to pass them as parameters to the UserLogin class that you have created.

Something like:

```
public class UserLogin
{
     private final LinkedList<datauser> ll1;
     private final LinkedList<task> taskLL;
     private final LinkedList<task> progressLL;
     private final LinkedList<task> completeLL;
     public class UserLogin(LinkedList<datauser> ll1, LinkedList<task> taskLL, LinkedList<task> progressLL, LinkedList<task> completeLL)
     {
        this.ll1 = ll1;
        this.taskLL = taskLL;
        this.progressLL = progressLL;
        this.completeLL = completeLL;
     }  

    //now you should be able to use the linked lists within the event handler
    private void submitBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    String user = jTextField1.getText();
    String userPW = jTextField2.getText();

    try {
        //below userLL is not accessible because it can't be found.
        dataUser.userDataSearch(userLL, userPW);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "was not found", "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        return;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE based on comment from the OP.**
Within the main method you would then initialize UserLogin like shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   LinkedList<datauser> ll1 = new LinkedList<datauser>();
   LinkedList<datauser> taskLL = new LinkedList<datauser>();
   LinkedList<datauser> progressLL = new LinkedList<datauser>();
   LinkedList<datauser> completeLL = new LinkedList<datauser>();

   //feed data within the above linked lists..
   ...

  //initialize the user login class with the linked lists you created
   UserLogin userLogin = new userLogin(ll1,taskLL, progressLL, completeLL);
}
```

On a general note - you may want to take a look at core Java concepts related to object creation in case you have not worked extensively with java before.

Comment: Does this mean I'm not declaring my LinkedList in main?  So If I were to declare one in main, load the linked list with data from a file, the LinkedList created in userLogin would be a different linked list?

Comment: @user3622460 In the example code shown above, you have only declared some instances of LinkedList but *not* yet initialized them. You can now initialize your linked lists in main() and then pass them to the UserLogin() constructor. I will update the answer to show this step.